# Excel - Extract a certain occurrence of strings a certain number of times

Tags: excel

I don't know exactly how to title my question but here is my problem:

I have cells in a column with URLs listed in each one of them (the quantity varies each cell) and separated by a " | ". For example the contents of **A1**:

```
www.google.com | www.facebook.com | www.twitter.com | www.stackoverflow.com | www.yahoo.com
```

I would like to extract into a new column, just the 3 first URLs of each cell. If more, it will be ignored, if less, it will extract all available ones.

So following the example, **B1** would contain:

```
www.google.com | www.facebook.com | www.twitter.com
```

How would I go to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",CHAR(1),3))-2),A1)
```

The `IFERROR()` will come into play when your string does not have three instances of `|` (I.E. you have 3 or less websites listed). If that is the case, then the string you have in `A1` is already the string you want so we simply return that value.